# Python Django - Upload a Picture to see in a browser in a dev-mode

Tags: python, django, browser, settings, django-urls

I'm trying to develop a blog website in a dev-mode in my localhost. When I'm trying to review my profile pictures in browser right after I upload my urls.py and settings.py; I'm havving error in the bottom. I'have tried other solutions mentioned in similar topics but those didnt' help.

My base doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Empty static prefix not permitted

Urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views  
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings  
from django.conf.urls.static import static  

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),  
path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),  
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),  
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),  
path('', include('blog.urls')),  ]

if settings.DEBUG: 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I've added this quote in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDUA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: your MEDIA spelling is wrong in settings.py.

Comment: Hahah :) is that it really? God! You saved me. Many thanks